# The "string" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer. Received type object

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Getting this error in the given code. I am calling this method on file upload and it is going to catch block.

`ERR:  TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "string" argument must be one of type string, Buffer, or ArrayBuffer. Received type object`

```
        try{
          request
            .post(url)
            .set(postHeaders)
            .send(postData)
            .end(function (err, response) {
                if(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    res.send(errorJson);
                    return;
                }
                res.set(response.header);
                res.send(response.text);
            });
          } catch(err){
              console.log("error" , err)
          }
```

The header is

`'content-type': 'multipart/form-data;'`

Answer (score 1):

From the looks of it you are using `superagent` to perform the upload. Since you're intending to do a `multipart/form-data` upload, you cannot use `.send()`. From the [docs](https://visionmedia.github.io/superagent/#multipart-requests):

> Multipart requests SuperAgent is also great for building multipart
> requests for which it provides methods .attach() and .field().
>
> When you use .field() or .attach() you can't use .send() and you must
> not set Content-Type (the correct type will be set for you)

So you need to change your code to:

```
request
       .post(url)            
       .field(<setYourFieldDataHere>) // or use .attach() if you want to upload files
       //
```